# Should it be "C are similar" or "are similar to C"?

Tags: word-order

I want to shorten the sentence:

> The relative contributions of several A to B are similar to the contributions of several A to C

Are either of the following better, or neither?

1. The contributions of several A to B and C are similar.
2. The contributions of several A to B are similar to C

Comment: In the first one, the contributions are similar to other contributions. In the second one, the contributions are similar to cheesecake. Or whatever C is. What *do* you wish to compare the contributions to? The two sentences are saying completely different things.

Comment: Without knowing, generally speaking, what A, B, and C are, it's impossible to say.

Comment: Are the “several A” (which, by the way, grates on my ears) contributing to B the same “several A” contributing to C or are the different “several A’s”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, I think if you have to pick one out, then you should try the first.
For the second, let's say that "*sb./sth.* be similar to *sb./sth.*" is a conventional phrase. And in your second alternative, it may cause an ambiguity that the similarity are between **A** and C but not **B** and C.

So I would like to recommend the first. And I think it is well shortened.